# VectorDrawable icons: approach to color changing

Tags: android, material-design, android-menu, vector-graphics, android-vectordrawable

I have some navigation menu with vector drawable icons and i want to change icons color according to menu item state.
To do it i can (using selector of course):
  change icon tint color
    or 
  replace icon itself

Which approach is better?

I saw how tint color settings distorts border of vector icon in Android Studio preview mode.
But how much the tint color usage distorts vector icons on real devices?